# Few issues with Tikz Calendar

Tags: tikz-calendar

I have been trying to implement my own agenda since those from the store never really satisfied me. I have now more or less what I wanted to get. I still have minor issues I can't workaround. So if someone has any tips :

1. I display only Monday, Thursday and Friday on the calendar (that appears on each weekly page in the upper right corner). So far the only working solution I have found is a negative "xshift" on days I don't want to display, otherwise, a blank space remains. But for some reason, it works fine except on weeks where the monday beglon to another month than the Thursday and Friday. In that case, a larger blank space is added for some reason, and I don't know why.
2. The calendar displayed on each page do not show the last vertical line whilst it is written in the tabular definition I use for the daytext...
3. The names of the days and the month refuse to translate to french, and I cant figure out why, I paid attention to the usepackage position but still, it does not work.
4. A great icing would be to display a different calendar depending on the week (the value of \n in my code, some calendar if \n is odd, another if \n is even). I don't know how to do that.

[image: A regular week with issues 2 and 3]
A regular week with issues 2 and 3
[image: The ugly week with issue 1 (and 2 and 3 for that matters)]
The ugly week with issue 1 (and 2 and 3 for that matters)

Thanks a lot for any input!
Cheers!

My code below :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{advdate}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\AdvanceDate[1][\@ne]{\global\advance\day#1 \FixDate}
\makeatother

\usepackage{tgheros,tikz,array}
\usetikzlibrary{calendar}
\usepackage[margin=1.25in,noheadfoot=true]{geometry}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[french]{translator}


%=========================================================
%== Page characteristics (Page Setup) ====================
\setlength{\textwidth}{126mm}
\setlength{\textheight}{230.0mm}
\setlength{\topmargin}{-30mm}
\setlength{\hoffset}{-20mm}
\setlength{\marginparwidth}{-20mm}
\setlength{\footskip}{0mm}
\setlength{\headheight}{11mm}
\setlength{\headsep}{4mm}
\setlength{\parindent}{0cm}
%=========================================================

\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds, positioning, scopes}
\newcommand{\textoverline}[1]{$\overline{\mbox{#1}}$}
\usepackage[absolute,overlay,showboxes]{textpos}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\definecolor{mygrey}{RGB}{239,239,239}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\begin{document}

\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{0.1pt}
\sffamily
\footnotesize

\newcommand\mondaytext[2]{%
  \begin{tabular}{|>{\mdseries\footnotesize}cp{1cm}|cp{1cm}|}
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{#1 #2} \\
    \hline
    \begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}8:35 \\ 9:30\end{tabular}& \\ \hline
    \begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}9:30 \\ 10:25\end{tabular} & \textbf{4D} \\\hline\hline
    \begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}10:40 \\ 11:35\end{tabular} & \textbf{4B}\\\hline
    \begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}11:35 \\ 12:30\end{tabular} & \\\hline\hline
    \begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}12:30\\ 13:05\end{tabular}  & \\\hline\hline
    \begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}13:05\\14:00 \end{tabular}  & \\\hline
    \begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}14:00\\14:55 \end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}{@{}c|c@{}}&\textbf{4B}\end{tabular}\\\hline\hline
    \begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}15:10\\16:05 \end{tabular}& \textbf{4C}\\\hline
  \end{tabular}
}
\newcommand\thursdaytext[2]{%
  \begin{tabular}{|>{\mdseries\footnotesize}cp{1cm}|cp{1cm}|}
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{#1 #2} \\
    \hline
    \begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}8:35 \\ 9:30\end{tabular}& \textbf{4D}\\ \hline
    \begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}9:30 \\ 10:25\end{tabular} & \textbf{4B}\\\hline\hline
    \begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}10:40 \\ 11:35\end{tabular} & \textbf{4C}\\\hline
    \begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}11:35 \\ 12:30\end{tabular} & \\\hline\hline
    \begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}12:30\\ 13:05\end{tabular}  & \\\hline\hline
    \begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}13:05\\14:00 \end{tabular}  & \begin{tabular}{@{}c|c@{}}\textbf{4D}&\end{tabular}\\\hline
    \begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}14:00\\14:55 \end{tabular} & \\\hline\hline
    \begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}15:10\\16:05 \end{tabular}& \\\hline
  \end{tabular}
}
\newcommand\fridaytext[2]{%
  \begin{tabular}{|>{\mdseries\footnotesize}p{1cm}|cp{1cm}|}
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{#1 #2} \\
    \hline
    \begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}8:35 \\ 9:30\end{tabular}& \textbf{DF:3C}\\ \hline
    \begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}9:30 \\ 10:25\end{tabular} & \textbf{4D} \\\hline\hline
    \begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}10:40 \\ 11:35\end{tabular} & \\\hline
    \begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}11:35 \\ 12:30\end{tabular} & \\\hline\hline
    \begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}12:30\\ 13:05\end{tabular}  & \\\hline\hline
    \begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}13:05\\14:00 \end{tabular}  & \begin{tabular}{@{}c|c@{}}& \textbf{4C}\end{tabular} \\\hline
    \begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}14:00\\14:55 \end{tabular} & \textbf{4D}\\\hline\hline
    \begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}15:10\\16:05 \end{tabular}& \textbf{4C}\\\hline
  \end{tabular}
}

\setlength{\skip\footins}{0cm}
\pagestyle{empty}
\SetDate[31/08/2020]
\foreach \n in {1,...,45}{

\begin{textblock}{8}(2,1.25)

  \textblockcolour{mygrey!40}
  \vspace{5mm}
    { \qquad \bfseries Notes : }
  \vspace{26mm}

  \vspace{25mm}
\end{textblock}
\begin{textblock}{15}(2,14.5)

  \textblockcolour{mygrey!40}
  \vspace{2mm}
    { \quad \bfseries Remarques : }
  \vspace{18mm}
\end{textblock}
\enlargethispage{40pt}
\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{0.5pt}
\arrayrulecolor{black}
\LARGE PLANNING DE LA SEMAINE \n \footnotesize
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay,shift={(5,-3.5)}]
  \calendar (cal)
  [dates=\year-\month-\day to \year-\month-\day+5,day list right,day xshift=3cm,
   execute before day scope=
  {
    \ifdate{Tuesday,Wednesday}{\pgftransformxshift{-3cm}}{}
    },
    day text={},
    execute at begin day scope={
    \ifdate{Monday}{\tikzmonthcode}{}},
    set style={{every month}+=[anchor=base east,font=\bfseries\large,xshift=-2.5em,yshift=12em]},
%  execute after day scope={\ifdate{Sunday}{\pgftransformyshift{-30em},\pgftransformxshift{-10.1cm}}{}}
  ]
  if(Monday) [day text={\mondaytext{\%wt}{\%d0}}]
  if(Thursday) [day text={\thursdaytext{\%wt}{\%d0}}]
  if(Friday) [day text={\fridaytext{\%wt}{\%d0}}]  
  if (weekend) [font=\bfseries]
  if (Sunday) [red];
%  \node[above right,font=\bfseries\footnotesize] at (cal-2020-09-14.north west)
%    {14--18 Septembre 2020};
\end{tikzpicture}
\\
\\
\\
\\
\\
\\
\\
\\
\\
\\
\\
\\
\\
\\
\\
\\
\\
\\
\\
\\
\\
\\
\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{0.1pt}
\arrayrulecolor{black!60}
\begin{tabular}{p{19cm}}
\textbf{LUNDI :} \\
\hline \\
\hline \\
\hline \\
\hline \\
\hline \\
\hline \\
\hline \\
\hline \\
\hline \\
\hline \\
\hline \\
\hline \\
\hline \\
\hline \\
\hline \\
\\
\textbf{JEUDI :} \\
\hline \\
\hline \\
\hline \\
\hline \\
\hline \\
\hline \\
\hline \\
\hline \\
\hline \\
\hline \\
\hline \\
\hline \\
\hline \\
\hline \\
\hline \\
\\
\textbf{VENDREDI :} \\
\hline \\
\hline \\
\hline \\
\hline \\
\hline \\
\hline \\
\hline \\
\hline \\
\hline \\
\hline \\
\hline \\
\hline \\
\hline \\
\hline \\
\hline \\
\hline 
\end{tabular}

\AdvanceDate[7]

\newpage
}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Not a complete answer but part of it has been solved in this other post : https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/563475/problem-with-a-test-in-if-statement