# Problem with a test in if statement

Tags: conditionals, date, ifthenelse, variable

I'm having trouble with the implementation of a if statement. I want to know if today and five days from now happen in the same month. I get the correct values of the corresponding month to print but when I want to test if both numbers are equal it does not work. The test is always false.
It probably has something to do with the \newcommand that does not store the expected result or something like that but I cant find a workaround.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{advdate}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\AdvanceDate[1][\@ne]{\global\advance\day#1 \FixDate}
\makeatother
\usepackage{ifthen}

\begin{document}
\SetDate[30/08/2020]

\newcommand{\dd}{{\AdvanceDate[0]\the\month}}
\newcommand{\ddo}{{\AdvanceDate[1]\the\month}}
\newcommand{\ddf}{{\AdvanceDate[5]\the\month}}


\today \quad is during month \dd \quad and tomorrow is during month \ddo \quad but we are still {\AdvanceDate[-1]\today}
\newline

\today \quad is during month \dd \quad and five days from now is during month \ddf \quad but we are still {\AdvanceDate[-5]\today}
\newline

"Today and tomorrow happen in the same month" is \ifthenelse{\equal{\dd}{\ddo}}{TRUE}{FALSE} and we are still \today
\newline

"Today and five days from now happen in the same month" is \ifthenelse{\equal{\dd}{\ddf}}{TRUE}{FALSE} but we are still {\AdvanceDate[-5]\today}

\end{document}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The macro `\dd` does not directly deliver `\the\month`, but does several assignment instructions in order to get at it.

You also don't want to do global assignments to `\day`.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{advdate}
\usepackage{ifthen}

\newcommand{\ifsamemonthTF}[4]{%
  \begingroup % compute the first date's month
  \AdvanceDate[#1]%
  \edef\x{\endgroup\def\noexpand\firstincrementmonth{\the\month}}\x
  \begingroup % compute the first date's month
  \AdvanceDate[#2]%
  \edef\x{\endgroup\def\noexpand\secondincrementmonth{\the\month}}\x
  \ifthenelse{\firstincrementmonth=\secondincrementmonth}{#3}{#4}%
}
\newcommand{\dd}{{\AdvanceDate[0]\the\month}}
\newcommand{\ddo}{{\AdvanceDate[1]\the\month}}
\newcommand{\ddf}{{\AdvanceDate[5]\the\month}}

\begin{document}
\SetDate[30/08/2020]

\today\ is during month \dd\ and tomorrow is during 
month \ddo\ but we are still \today

\today\ is during month \dd\ and five days from now is during 
month \ddf\ but we are still \today

``Today and tomorrow happen in the same month'' is 
\ifsamemonthTF{0}{1}{TRUE}{FALSE} and we are still \today

``Today and five days from now happen in the same month'' is 
\ifsamemonthTF{0}{5}{TRUE}{FALSE} but we are still \today

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I didn't got much time to dive into it until now. That helped a lot, thanks!